# iOS youtube share with native dialog

Tags: ios, youtube, oauth-2.0, google-api

Is it possible to use native youtube share dialog like it's done in standard iOS Photos app?
[image]

or it doesn't make a sence cause this standard app reproduces the same method like [here](http://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/youtube-api-on-ios/)?
how does it skip google's OAuth web-interface? Potentially iOS may grab user's google credentials? Or Apple has some privileged google API like they do for facebook and twitter?

Comment: I have been research on this a lot and I found out that the app itself is made by Youtube developers or Google. I'm no expert, but maybe it's not possible. Here is it's homepage. https://www.youtube.com/capture